# Custom DSL runs in groovy 3.0.x but fails at runtime in 2.5.x

Tags: groovy

I have a strange runtime bug where custom DSL based on AbstractFactory compiles and runs fine with groovy 3.0.x but fails at runtime under 2.5.x.

Here's the code:

```
  @Test
  void sayTest() {
    PerCLScript script = percl.script {
      say language: 'en-US', loop: 1, conferenceId: 'confId', text: 'some text', enforcePCI: false
    }

    compare('[{"Say":{"language":"en-US","conferenceId":"confId","text":"some text","enforcePCI":false,"loop":1}}]', script.serializeToPerCL())
  }
```

Runtime error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.freeclimb.groovy.PerCLBuilderTest.say() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[language:en-US, loop:1, conferenceId:confId, text:some text, ...]]
Possible solutions: sms(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure), tap(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long)
```

I'm building with GmavenPlus 1.8.1, but I tried the eclipse-groovy-compiler with the same results.

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>compileTests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <invokeDynamic>true</invokeDynamic>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

PerCLBuilder

```
class PerCLBuilder extends FactoryBuilderSupport {

  private PerCLScript percl

  public PerCLBuilder(boolean init = true) {
    super(init)
  }

  def registerObjectFactories() {
    registerFactory('script', new ScriptFactory())
    registerFactory('say', new PerCLCommandFactory(Say.class))
...

  }

  class PerCLCommandFactory extends AbstractFactory {
    Class clazz;

    PerCLCommandFactory(Class clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("GrDeprecatedAPIUsage")
    Object newInstance(FactoryBuilderSupport builder, Object name, Object value, Map attributes)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
      clazz.newInstance()
    }
...
```

Comment: How is your `say` method defined?

Comment: registerFactory('say', new PerCLCommandFactory(Say.class))


I'm using the FactoryBuilderSupport class.  PerCLCommandFactory creates a new instance based on the class.  I think there is a better way to do this with the delegates annotation but this was working, and I was going to circle back on that issue later.

Comment: @PaulKing I added some more code details. Thanks.